# Changing the Adobe Acrobat version on uploaded PDFs

Tags: php, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I have a page where several admin users can upload PDFs to be viewable on a site.  The users start with a doc in Word and save it as a PDF prior to uploading.

My problem is, the PDF version is usually the latest version of Adobe Reader.  When some users come along to view the PDF and have a lower version of Adobe Reader, they are receiving error messages that they either can't view the PDF or they don't have the reader installed.  I'm sure the error is coming from the version of the PDF.

**Question**:  Is there a way to modify the PDF version as it is being uploaded to the site?  I see that from Acrobat Pro, I can Optimize the PDF and change the "MAKE COMPATIBLE WITH" setting to lower the version required.  Just wondering if there is a way to do it via code when the PDF gets uploaded?  Some (most) of my admins don't have the skills/knowledge to change the version as they are saving the original PDF.  I'm just trying to dumb it down for them.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What operating system is your web server on?

Comment: Linux running Apache.

Comment: You may be able to do this my compressing the files using `pdftk`... something like `pdftk file1.pdf output file2.pdf compress`, though I'm not sure what effect that would have on compatible versions. Alternately you could try installing `ghostscript` and running something like this: `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf`, which will "print" the pdf... I believe this will standardize the version (that `gs` command was originally posted by [imriss](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2026975/imriss)

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll look into this function.